# AngularJS resource with explicit file type extension and POST

Tags: angularjs

Angular $resource does a pretty good job figuring out how to handle POST and GET query with no resource ID; it intelligently removes the trailing slash:

```
resource('/users/:user',{user:'@id'},{})
```

Will give the correct:

```
GET /users/25 (for User.get())
POST /users (for new creation)
GET /users  (for User.query())
```

Note that for creation and `User.query()` is correctly stripped the trailing slash when `:user` was blank.

However, if you add a file type extension, it stops stripping the trailing slash

```
resource('/users/:user.json',{user:'@id'},{})
```

Will give

```
GET /users/25.json (CORRECT)
POST /users/.json (BAD: should be /users.json)
GET /users/.json (BAD: should be /users.json)
```

Is there any way to get it to either:

- intelligently strip the trailing slash even with a file type; OR
- put on the '.json' extension afterwards

This is a pretty common pattern, supported as a basic format in Sinatra (RoR) and express (node), and is even part of the basic angular tutorial at http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11

How do I get it to do the right thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a bug, which seems to be fixed in Version 1.1.5: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5306136

Comment: I don't know why, but this bugfix was not merged into 1.0.7.

Comment: I am using resource 1.1.5 with angular 1.0.7, but keeping an eye our for incompatibilities.